# Unity3d и облако

Tags: android, ios, unity3d, azure, облако

Делаю игру на Unity. Хочу сохранять лучший счет в облаке, чтобы при удалении игры он сохранился или при заходе с другого устройства он тоже был сохранен. Подскажите через что это лучше реализовать. Игра на мобильные платформы android, windows phone, iOS. Думаю использовать Azure от Microsoft.

Comment: Azure дорогой. Для такой задачи хватит чего-нибудь подешевле. На Digital Ocean за 10-20 долларов можно взять машинку, которой хватит под ваши задачи.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Для этого можно воспользоваться Azure Websites с Free-планом и вообще за бесплатно реализовать всё это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на твоём месте использовал **Azure Websites** (Они же Azure **App Services**). Создал бы **REST API** который бы там захостил и писал бы через него запросы в твою базу данных с сэйвами. Если запросов не так много и не надо шифровать трафик, то можешь вообще воспользоваться **Free**-планом. Вроде бы должно хватить.

Подробности о стоимости смотри тут: [App Service Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/)